# Bootstrap CSS Panel Title Adjustment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a panel I am using to hold a table of data. I am using a search box and pagination on this to allow for some filtering options but the spacing and margins are just not as fine tuned as I would like.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading"><span class="title"><i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Open Items</span>  <span class="col-xs-3 pull-right"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchbox" placeholder="Search the results..."></span>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">

    <table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Username</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

    </div>
<div class="panel-footer">
    <ul class="pagination pull-right">
        <li class="disabled"><a aria-label="Previous" href="#"><span aria-hidden="true">«</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">1 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">4</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">5</a>
        </li>
        <li><a aria-label="Next" href="#"><span aria-hidden="true">»</span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <br />
    <br />
</div>
```

In the image below, I am trying to vertically center the Title within the heading but it seems that the search box is causing it to push to the top.

Also, the pagination at the bottom still have a gap in it even though I took out the margins.
[image]

Here is a fiddle of what I am trying to accomplish: http://jsfiddle.net/x5o9dtt2/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your CSS with this one -

```
.panel-footer {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
    padding: 5px;
    line-height: 17px;
}
.panel-heading {
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    line-height: 35px;
    padding: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.pagination {
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

This is the [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/x5o9dtt2/3/)

Answer (score 0):

The title can be vertically aligned with the search by setting a line-height.

The pagination gap is caused by padding of the footer panel and not the margins of the pagination. Also I have increased the line-height of the pagination since the space beneath the pagination is unknown.

```css
.panel-footer {
  padding: 0;
}
.panel-heading {
  line-height: 35px;
  padding: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.pagination > li > a,
.pagination > li > span {
  line-height: 1.9;
}
```

**Output:**

[image: Vertically aligned title]

[**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/qdvuLxb1/)